# On the basis of position accepted, how to display the image?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview

```
public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Integer[] ImgPreview = { R.drawable.mlview1, R.drawable.mlview2,
            R.drawable.mlview3 };
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_prev);

        Intent intent = null;
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        int position = b.getInt("position");

        // here, what to do?
        if (position == 0) {

        }
```

From the previous activity, it fetches the parameter "position" , on the basis of the value of "position", it should display the image. for ex: if position 0, then image "mlview1" is displayed and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this..

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview); // Here R.id.imageview is id of ImageView fro your image_prev xml file.. change according it..
imageView.setImageResource(ImgPreview[position]);
```